# Is it possible to train a neural network with multiple hidden layers in Vowpal Wabbit?

Tags: neural-network, vowpalwabbit

I know that the syntax for training a single-layer neural network is:

```
vw -d data.vw --nn 10
```

(Thanks,  [FastML](http://fastml.com/go-non-linear-with-vowpal-wabbit/))

What if I'd like to add a second layer, say with 5 nodes? Is that possible?

**UPDATE**

For those of you interested in using VW neural nets in an applied setting I've posted a public Google drive linked to a worked example relating to this question   here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzKSYsAMaJLjZzJlWFA2N3NnZGc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VW doesn't have the ability to construct more than 1 hidden layer (using `-nn X`). You'd have to use a different non-linear algorithm or a different framework.

Comment: By the way, when you say I'd have to use a different "non-linear algorithm" do you have anything in mind for Vowpal specifically? We absolutely love VW's speed of execution, it's ability to interact an arbitrary number of feature space, and it's ability to pick out time-continuous affects, but I'm not sure how good it is at describing a high degree of non-linearity (which complex regression problems pretty much always have).

Comment: I'm not sure. But I'd try if 1 layer is sufficient for your data (it is in most cases: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/17545/universal-approximation-theorem-neural-networks )

Comment: Right on, thanks for the link. Last two questions for you for now--have you found that the performance of the VW nnet improves when the features are mean-variance scaled, or is the algorithm flexible enough to accommodate a non-scaled set of features? Is it just as good for binary encoded [-1, 1] as continuous target variables?